# IQ Test question - vertical, horizontal and diagonal lines within a square

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

> ***Which of the six tiles below is missing?*** 
>  
>  [image: IQ Question]

I honestly do not know the answer. I took a screenshot of this from an online IQ test a while back. If you know where it is from, please let me know, and I will [provide attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

---

**Edit:**
Thanks to a fellow user, [here](https://www.test-iq.org/free-quiz/) is the website from which this question is taken.

Comment: Cough cough XOR

Comment: Question comes from [this website](https://www.test-iq.org/free-quiz/). 100% sure, even the colours are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> B

Sorry if I answered too fast.

This is because:

> In a given row, the lines that are in the same position and positioning are taken away. The lines that are left combine to make the third picture.

Comment: Wait, that was it? Why did I not see that?! I answered all the other test questions except this one (this one was the hardest, for me). Eh well, don't apologise for solving this too fast! When would you like the tick? :D

Comment: nice catch @Alto

Comment: Oh. I would like it super fast, please.

Comment: Not fast as in 1 year, but fast as in today.