# IQ test question - Almost paper folding, but maybe not?

Tags: visual, progressive-matrix

This is one of the random IQ test puzzles available [here](https://www.test-iq.org/free-quiz/). I can not find a clue to this at all and this is sort of bugging me for some time now.

It could be some kind of paper folding or just rotations; I am not sure though.

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome! You will need to credit the website you found this from in your question, just to add attribution.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I do know where this question comes from, it comes from [this IQ test website](https://www.test-iq.org/free-quiz/). I am 100% sure, even the colours are the same. It is question 2 of the quiz.

Comment: @user71981 thank you for finding that! I’ll add it in now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which of the six tiles is missing? — An IQ Test Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/which-of-the-six-tiles-is-missing-an-iq-test-question)

Comment: The title of the question in my last comment is incorrect since I edited the title. Here is the new link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/iq-test-question-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-lines-within-a-square

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an

> XOR operation, acting from left to right.
>
> (There may be some pattern acting top to bottom, but I haven't spotted it)

So

> If you 'add' the left and the middle squares, it works as an XOR to produce the right square. So if a line is present in both squares, or in neither, then it won't be in the right square.

Therefore the answer is:

> **B**

Answer (score 3):

Just to add my idea into the pot, I guessed

> B

Because:

> it's the only unique answer compared to all of the given images, allowing for rotations. I'm not sure if that's the intended way to answer it, but it matches the previous answer.

Neat!